# Can a engine become scorched with out ever running hot or overheating?

Tags: engine, vw

My 2014 VW Tiguan's oil light came on while driving home from out of town with about 100 mile to go, I immediately exited the highway to check it. When I did I saw nothing unusual, the oil level was not low, there was no smell of burnt oil. I figured looks ok but I'd better take it to my mechanic as soon as I got home.

I then continued home stopping halfway again checking the oil, still nothing unusual so again I continued, calling my mechanic on the way. He told me stop in on my way home, I brought it directly to him. After looking at it, he said he wasn't sure what the problem was, but knowing it was still under warranty to take it to the dealership, which I did.

When I spoke with them the next day, they said they would contact the warranty company and get back to me, 2 days later he call informing me the warranty company was requesting the service records, after I provided he said he would submit them and get back to me. A few days later he call saying the claim was filed and the warranty company was sending an adjuster out and that in order for the adjuster to inspect the engine the valve cover had to be taken off, telling me shuold the claim be denied I would be responsible for the cost, $400, which seemed kinda steep but what could I do. He told me once the adjuster inspected it he would be in touch.

A week later I get the call, claim denied as they concluded improper maintenance, I don't understand how that's possible as I've been taking my cars to the same mechanic, who by the way is one of the most reputable mechanic in the entire area the shop has been open and operating in the same location for over 50 years. He has changed my oil every three month and uses synthetic oil. The adjuster came to the conclusions stating the rocker were scorched, I don't understand how this could be, especially as I would think if this were true at some point wouldn't the engine overheated or at least running hot at some point?

Is this possible? The dealership sold me this warranty for $2500. And now they want me to pay over $500 just to get it back, that's without even putting the valve cover back on, leaving me with an inoperable vehicle that I still have almost 3 years to pay on. Any advice would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The rockers being scorched is a symptom, not a cause, so I certainly wouldn't accept that - you need to be asking why the rockers are scorched. The most likely cause would be oil starvation - either a lack of oil, a problem with the pump or a blockage stopping the oil from reaching the head. You've already confirmed that it wasn't a lack of oil, and that it was recently changed (I presume you have paperwork from your mechanic to back that up).

Unfortunately, as you've found, aftermarket vehicle warranties are usually not worth the paper they are printed on, as they will do anything to get out of paying up and try all sorts of excuses to pass the blame onto you...

One for the lawyers I'm afraid...

Comment: Thank you for your input. And I'm finding out how right u are. As the warranty company set there own adjuster not a 3rd party that would be impartial.